# change square's color according to combobox-uwp

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-10-universal

I have been trying to change a square's filling(color) in universal windows (c#).
It has worked for me in wpf but doesn't work for universal windows.
I know it should be different but all  of the solutions I found online included use in `Color` and my code doesn't recognize that. I have tried importing like so : `Windows.UI.Color` but it also doesn't recognize.

this is what I have been trying to do with my code :

```
string ComboText = ((ComboBoxItem)ComboBox1.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();
if (ComboText != "")
{
    var converter = new System.Windows.Media.BrushConverter();
    var brush = (Brush)converter.ConvertFromString(ComboBox1.Text);
    rect.Fill = brush;
}
```

I have found this solution on the interenet :

```
var color = (Color)XamlBindingHelper.ConvertValue(typeof(Color), ComboText);
var brush = new SolidColorBrush(color);
rect.Fill = brush;
```

However, my code doesn't recognize either `Color` or `XamlBindingHelper`. Does anyone have a clue what I should do?

Comment: "The name 'XamlBindingHelper' does not exist in the current context" and for the color it's : "the type or namespace 'Color' could not be found"

Comment: I didn't have "using Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup; " I have now added it and it solved the XamlBindingHelper problem but it still doesn't recognize the color

Comment: I got that using statement from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.markup.xamlbindinghelper (under namespace). What is the appropriate namespace for `Color`?

Comment: Thanks! I found out I didn't have the namespace "Windows.UI " that I though I had